# Firefox on ubuntu does not restore tabs from last time

Tags: firefox, 14.10, sync

Okay, this is my first question, I'll try to explain what happens. I use Firefox Sync in three devices (my notebook running Ubuntu 14.10 and two other Windows machines), and I use the "show my windows and tabs from last time" setting on them all, but since the upgrade from Trusty to Utopic, this setting doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu. It's okay on both other two Windows devices I use, only on Ubuntu I have this problem - everytime I close Firefox, when I open it again, it shows me the default Ubuntu start page. I don't know if it happens because I don't sync the tabs, only the rest of the stuff. And I have already turned off the sync, modified things on about:config following tutorials and nothing works... I've been thinking about downgrading back to trusty, since I maintain OS and archives in a separate partition... What could be going on?

Comment: What did you modify in about:config?

Comment: I just changed 'browser.sessionstore.restore_hidden_tabs', 'browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs_on_demand' and 'browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once' from false to true. // PS: Sorry lasting this much to answer - no time this week!

Comment: Now w/ personal help of my boyfriend (who understands much more about Ubuntu than me) I've changed 'privacy.clearOnShutdown.session' and 'services.sync.prefs.sync.privacy.clearOnShutdown.sessions' from true to false and nothing works. He also suggested me to purge Firefox and reinstall it, but when I log in to Sync again it may happen again. Argh ><

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem since I updated FF to ver 35. I'm using Elementary OS.

I got it working by making "refresh firefox": https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Aftert that, tried and it was working. Logged in to sync and after all addons were syncronized it keeps working Ok. I have done several shutdown to firefox and all tabs restored when I open FF.